# What can I change in my code to make this work

Tags: html

Trying to get music to play continuously on weebly website when pages are changed

I tried several things.. adding audio player to each page, changing footer codes in SEO,  adding header and footer code to each page. every time the music starts over as you click on a new page

supposedly this is used to have music play continuously page to page but it restarts on each page

Comment: Please share your code so we can help you better.

Comment: Hi Denise and welcome to Stack Overflow. There's little chance anyone will be able to assist you without seeing the code you've written. To increase the likelihood that someone will respond in the future, I recommend you review the guidelines on [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: In addition to this, most browsers actively discourage auto-playing music nowadays. They will mute it themselves until the user interacts with it.

Comment: sorry, as you can tell I don't know what I'm doing, but according to one site, they told me to add this to my SEO header  <embed src="https://box521.bluehost.com:2083/cpsess2573883129/frontend/bluehost/filemanager/showfile.html?file=01-RhapsodyInBlueOriginal1927Recording.mp3&fileop=&dir=%2Fhome5%2Fnfcollec%2Fpublic_html%2Fgeorgeskolerartgallery%2Ffiles%2Ftheme&dirop=&charset=&file_charset=&baseurl=&basedir=

 " autostart="true" loop="true" width="0" height="0">